# How to use a variable in a POSIX Path with AppleScript?

Tags: path, applescript, finder

I've been trying for a little while to swap out one of the parts in a POSIX Path with a variable but I've had no success.  This is the script I'm trying to develop:

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate POSIX file "/Users/**Variable**/Documents/img.jpg" to POSIX file "/Users/**Variable**/Desktop/" with replacing
end tell
```

The parts in the path are the places where I want the variable to be present.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: So what I want is instead of the bits in bold actually being a directory, I want them to be a variable

Comment: simple syntax using relative paths : `duplicate file ((path to documents folder as text) & "img.jpg") to desktop with replacing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break the string with ampersands & and the variable.

Also, it's good practice to convert posix paths to Mac standard colon: paths prior to scripting Finder. Finder's duplicate function has been buggy since 10.9 in these ways.
I have broken out some of the coercions so you can see what's going on.

```
-- define file and user names
set fileName to "img.jpg"
set user1 to "Mitc"
set user2 to "Mitc"

-- create posix path strings
set path1 to "/Users/" & user1 & "/Documents/" & fileName
set path2 to "/Users/" & user2 & "/Desktop/"

-- convert posix paths into colon paths
set ref1 to (POSIX file path1) as string
set ref2 to (POSIX file path2) as string

-- display dialog ref1 & return & ref2 -- to test
tell application "Finder" to duplicate alias ref1 to alias ref2 with replacing
```

Comment: Sorry it was the first one I saw but your is still a very accurate answer to what I needed

Comment: Actually I seem to be getting an error with both of them D: "error "Finder got an error: Can’t set POSIX file \"/Users/MitchSimpson/Desktop/\" to POSIX file \"/Users/MitchSimpson/Documents/img.jpg\"." number -10006 from file "Macintosh HD:Users:MitchSimpson:Desktop:""

Comment: Finder's Duplicate is buggy. It also doesn't like posix path file references. I modified the script to convert them to colon based paths first. Should work.

Comment: I don't know if its just a bug but I seem to be getting an error about my desktop alias "File alias Macintosh HD:Users:Mitc/Desktop/ wasn’t found." number -43

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a bug I introduced as I made the script more 'fancy', breaking out the file name into a property as well. I have spread out the code such that it works now again. (Do make sure you're spelling "Mitc/Mitch" correctly.)

Comment: Okay thanks!, the mitc thing was just me pasting the code and writing it into the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the " & to tell the script to stop reading the directory and add the variable so here is the result:

```
tell application "Finder"
     duplicate POSIX file "/Users/" & variable & "/Documents/img.jpg" to POSIX file "/Users/" & variable & "/Desktop/" with replacing
end tell
```

(make sure you use the "set" command to make the variable, EG.)

```
set variable to "text"
```

Hope this helped!